# Simple prop example but props are not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Going through the next chapter in a react book I decided to try to build out some code to test out how props work in react. I have the following app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
// Import Component
import PropExample from './simple-props'
const ctitle = "Sample app"
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">{ctitle}</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <div className='custom-components-list'>
          <PropExample />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Component `PropExample` is making use of the container/containee design pattern. So it has two components within it `PropX` and `Card`. PropX the parent fetches data from an api and updates it's state. Card receives that data via props and renders it.

The code for both components is as follows:

```
/*
  Simple component to read from api and present data
  Propx to get data from api and function as container to Card component
  Card component to present data to UI and leverage material ui
*/
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Card from './card'
class PropX extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    state:{
      data:[{
        name: 'Grrot',
        city: "grav",
        zip: 32453
      },{
        name: 'Grrot',
        city: "grav",
        zip: 32453
      },{
        name: 'Grrot',
        city: "grav",
        zip: 32453
      }]
    }
  }
  //Lifecycle hook that will grab data right before component is mounted to the dom
  componentWillMount(){
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    fetch(url)
    .then((res)=>{ // Note that this a response object, need to look more into promises, fetch api and response object in javascript
      //console.log(`The response is ${res}`)
      return res.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
      //console.log(`The data is ${data}`)
      this.setState({data})
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(`The error is ${err}`)
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Card data={this.state}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default PropX
```

And Card:

```
/*
  Card component
  Reads data fetched from  parent PropX
  Produces Cards with sylized data
*/
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import ImageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Image';
import WorkIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Work';

class Card extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render(){
    return(
    <ul>
      {this.props.data.map(i => {
        return (
          <li key={i}> {i.name}</li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
    )
  }
}
export default Card
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
Card.render
card.js:21
  18 | render(){
  19 |   return(
  20 |   <ul>
> 21 |     {this.props.data.map(i => {
  22 |       return (
  23 |         <li key={i}> {i.name}</li>
  24 |       )
```

Removing `this` doesn't fix the issue. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

I am also trying to use material ui (installed with --save) but I'm not using any of the components as of yet since I can't figure out why I don't have data.

Comment: The issue in **PropX** component you try to pass to **Card** component Object `this.state` instead of Array `this.state.data`.
Try it out:

`<Card data={this.state.data}/>`

Comment: I did that previously and got a different error.

Comment: And in constructor use `this.state =` instead of `state: `

Comment: And finally be sure that data is Array here:
`.then(data => {
      //console.log(`The data is ${data}`)
      this.setState({data})
    })
`

Comment: @Callat did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Nope :( looking at your solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your constructor for PropX

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    state:{ // okay... so this is referenced where?
      data:[{
        name: 'Grrot',
        city: "grav",
        zip: 32453
      },{
        name: 'Grrot',
        city: "grav",
        zip: 32453
      },{
        name: 'Grrot',
        city: "grav",
        zip: 32453
      }]
    }
  }
```

You need to assign `state` as a property on `this` in the constructor so that later when you pass it, it's actually assigned

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { // now it's this.state
      data:[{
        name: 'Grrot',
        city: "grav",
        zip: 32453
      },{
        name: 'Grrot',
        city: "grav",
        zip: 32453
      },{
        name: 'Grrot',
        city: "grav",
        zip: 32453
      }]
    }
  }
```

Of course now when you call `.map()` in card you'll get a different error. What you probably wanted to do was pass `this.state.data` to the card instead

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <Card data={this.state.data}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: So you are saying instead of `state` go for `this.state`?

Comment: @Callat updated. You should not see what the different is. Before you had an unassigned state. now you have an assigned state

Comment: @Callat updated with fix for error regarding .map not being a function

Comment: Works like a charm! So A) `this.state.whateverthinginstate` is required to specify what part of the state you want to iterate over and B) state must be assigned with this.state correct?